# Convert NSString of a math equation to a value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring, expression-evaluation

I would like to know how to evaluate a string representation of an equation as if it were a real equation:

```
if(@"15+14==23")
{
    //True statement...
}
else
{
    //False statement....
}
```

I want to return "false" because 15+14 does not equal 23. How can I get this to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a simple equation parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582398/writing-a-simple-equation-parser)

Comment: Are these strings coming from a data source, or user input?  You will need to figure out what types of math equation's you want to support and then go from there. (ie what operands, how many operands and if the user will ever type ==) (Do you want support for 1*1*1*1x1*1=1 ?)

Comment: The string will come from a fixed data source, there are numbers from 0 - 20 , equation ( + - * / ) and equal (==)

Comment: We are trying to create a scrabble-like math equation game

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155360/convert-to-float-and-calculate/14155699#14155699

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example how to do it with `NSPredicate`:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"1+2==3"];
NSLog(@"%d", [p evaluateWithObject:nil]);
p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"1+2==4"];
NSLog(@"%d", [p evaluateWithObject:nil]);
```

The first `NSLog` produces `1` because `1+2==3` is true; the second produces `0`.

Comment: @Mithras: in the same spirit you could say Apple is being too nice to lazy programmers by providing objective c instead of assembly. Lazy programmers write code that is less functional/more buggy, not less code

Comment: @Mithras I don't think it's a case of "being nice": parsers are hard to get right, even by "hard-working" programmers using the right tools. Apple's offering a simple, easy to learn, solution for everyone helps the world by not breeding poorly-written parsers :)

Comment: @Dani It sounds to me like you don't want to learn and grow. This is typical of people who aren't too serious about programming.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It's not that hard to write a basic mathematical expression parser, and making the effort improves one's understanding and appreciation of computer science.

Comment: @Mithras Although it's not hard to write a parser, it's best to do it as an exercise while you're still in a high school or at a university. I wrote more than a dozen parsers myself, and my first three or four were throw-away code by most practical standards. My point is that learning exercises and production code are best kept separate.

Comment: @Mithras it may not be hard to write a basic parser, but as soon as you want to write one that correctly handles operator associativity, exponentiation, and negation, things get *really* complicated.  Even `NSPredicate` gets some things wrong.

Comment: @Mithras: I wrote enough parsers to learn and grow over that subject. However, I will not use a manuall one when NSPredicate is available, just like you won't write your own formatted printing function when printf is available.

Comment: @PunataroPuhnChaturaphit What about it? It is a valid predicate, it is just not obvious what it does.

Comment: @PunataroPuhnChaturaphit It does not look like the parser of the `predicateWithFormat:` method is smart enough to parse conditions on booleans: it fails to parse `(1<2)==(3<4)` as well. It handles integers OK, though.

Comment: Using `NSExpression` for this seems to be closer to the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785873/how-to-evaluate-the-string-equation-in-ios/16785975#16785975

Answer (score 3):

So, this is a problem that I believe is a lot more complicated than the linked question lets on (although the question is asking for a "simple" equation parser).

Fortunately for you, I think this is a really interesting problem and have already written one for you: [`DDMathParser`](https://github.com/davedelong/ddmathparser).

It has a [good amount of documentation](https://github.com/davedelong/ddmathparser/wiki), including things like [how to add it to your project](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Adding-DDMathParser-to-your-project) and a [high overview of its capabilities](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Usage).  It supports [all of the standard mathematical operators](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Operators), including logical and comparison operators (`||`, `&&`, `==`, `!=`, `<=`, etc).

In your case, you'd do something like this:

```
NSNumber *result = [@"15+14 == 23" numberByEvaluatingString];
if ([result boolValue] == YES) {
  ....True statement....
} else {
  .....False statement.....
}
```

As a heads up, `DDMathParser` is made available under the MIT license, which requires you to include the copyright information and the full text of the license in anything that uses it.

Comment: I'd bet you will never see your copyright notice in anyone's software on iTunes. The same type of laziness that causes a person to not want to learn how to write an expression evaluator will also incline them to basically steal from you. You would help society more by providing tutorials rather than completed code.

Comment: @Mithras actually, I know of several people who use it and are properly following the license.  And it's not "laziness" that dissuades people from writing an expression evaluator; it's that it's a *really hard problem* if you want it to be universally correct.  By your argument, Apple should just provide tutorials on how to implement touch handling, the responder chain, rotation detection, etc, instead of just giving us the UIKit framework. Yeah, not going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *equation = @"15+14==29";


NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:equation];

NSExpression *LeftExp = [pred leftExpression];

NSExpression *RightExp = [pred rightExpression];    


NSNumber *left = [LeftExp expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];

NSNumber *right = [RightExp expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];


if ([left isEqualToNumber:right]) {
    NSLog(@"yes left is equal to right");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"yes left is NOT equal to right");

}

NSLog(@"left %@", left); 

NSLog(@"right %@", right);
```

Comment: This is no different from @dasblinkenlight's answer; You've just broken out the left and right expressions instead of letting `NSPredicate` handle the comparison for you.

Comment: just for knowledge sharing buddy.