# How to evaluate the string equation in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, nsstring, nsinteger

Is there way to solve the string equations in `ios` ?

For example

Input:

`NSString * str =@"1+2";`

Output:

`NSInteger result = 3` // i.e sum of 1+2 from `str`

How to go about this and get expected result!

Please help!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use NSExpression for this:

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"1+2"];
NSLog(@"%@", [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil]);
```

For further information read the documentation of the used methods.

Comment: +1 This is correct.  You don't need something like my DDMathParser unless you need much more flexibility in the parsing/evaluation process.

Answer (score 4):

If your mathematical expressions are simple enough, you could go the manual route as suggested by Rajan Balana.

To evaluate more complex expressions, you could use/abuse `NSPredicate` in combination with `NSExpression` as described in this Blog post:http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1553469975/abusing-nspredicate

Note that `NSPredicate` is only necessary if your input is really an equation (including the right part):

```
NSPredicate* parsedExpression = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"1+2=x"];
NSExpression* leftPart = [(NSComparisonPredicate*)parsedExpression leftExpression];
NSNumber* evaluatedResult = [leftPart expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
NSLog(@"Expr:%@", evaluatedResult);
```

To achieve proper parsing, you can use one of the math parsers for Objective-C out there. I haven't used them myself, but the popular ones seem to be

- [GCMathParser](http://apptree.net/parser.htm)
- [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser)

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
NSString * str =@"1+2";

NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++) {
    sum += [[arr objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
}
NSLog(@"sum : %d",sum);
```

Output : sum = 6

You can use [NSExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html) also.

Expressions are the core of the predicate implementation. When **expressionValueWithObject:** is called, the expression is evaluated, and a value returned which can then be handled by an operator. Expressions can be anything from constants to method invocations. Scalars should be wrapped in appropriate NSValue classes.

Example :

```
    NSLog(@"sum : %@", [[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"1+4"] expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil]);
Output :- sum : 5
    NSLog(@"mulitple : %@", [[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"2*4"] expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil]);
Output :- mulitple : 8
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, You can get the components of the string separated by the sign "+" using this method and then you will get the array of components i.e. 1,2.

`NSArray* foo = [str componentsSeparatedByString: @"+"];`

`int result = [[foo objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] + [[foo objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];`

and then you can use the integer value for those two elements and add them and store the result in an integer variable.

Comment: what you will do if `*` instead of `+`??

Comment: @Anil replace that + with the * :)

Comment: @RajanBalana answer provided by AminNegm-Awad solves all the cases without having to write extra code!

Comment: @NeelamVerma then you need to go along with Amin Negm-Awad 's Answer. Cheers!

Comment: @RajanBalana have upvoted you cheers! atleast partial output ;)

Comment: @VinayakKini Thank you for your kindness and appreciation :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `subString` your string, and store each number in a new `NSstring`(integerValue) or in `Integer` variable.

> example:

```
NSString *str = @"1+2";
    int x = [[str substringToIndex:1]integerValue];
    int y = [[str substringFromIndex:1]integerValue];
    int z = x+y;
    NSLog(@"Sum === %d",z);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on complexity of your input string equations. You can use [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) for parsing mathematical equations and then calculate the equation from the `Abstract Syntact Tree (AST)`

But I expect you are looking for some easy, preferably already done solution. In that case you can take a try one of these (no guarantee, I haven't tried those, just googled):

- [DDMathParser](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1655852768/mathematically-evaluating-nsstrings)
- https://github.com/stribehou/Infix-expression-calculator