# How would I create a function in objective-c that would correctly output the results of in mathematical precedence?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to create a mathematical calculator in objective-C. I need it to run 
through a command line. The user will enter an equation like 4 + 2 * 12 etc. The output should calculate the 2 and 12 first because they are times by. How would I create a command line program that creates output based on mathematical order or precedence. for example solving whats in the brackets first then anything that is multiplied and or divided by etc etc.

Comment: Either try to solve the problem by thinking or [search for existing approaches](https://www.google.de/search?q=calculator+objective+c&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=xXbvWIKqCcjb8Aemn6iABA)  for your homework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to evaluate the string equation in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785873/how-to-evaluate-the-string-equation-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple programs available online for this here is just one http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Command-Prompt-Calculator, in the CMD line you can specify precedence by simply using parenthesis like the following C:> set /a ((2*12)+4) obviously replacing hard coded values with that passed to a variable.