# Techniques needed to write an arithmetic expression parser

Tags: algorithm, parsing, compilation

For some one how has only knowledge on tree data structure Is it evident for him to write an Arithmetic Expressions parser without the help of compilation techniques ?

Comment: Your question may be too broad for Stackoverflow but, before one judges this, would you explain what you mean by "evident"?

Comment: Are you familiar with Expression Trees?

Comment: @thb "evident" means simple and eazy to write just using basic programming techniques, without learning advanced compilation conceptes

Comment: @st0le i'm familiar with Trees data structure

Comment: @anouar204, My 2cents. Learn to build an Expression Tree and then Evaluation will be very easy. Also Use Java Math Expression Parser (Open Source) to look up how it's done.

Comment: I have heard somthing about grammar and lexical analysis, and need to know if those skilles are necessary to have a correct algorithm and not just plumbing, 
by plumbing i mean sothing like trying to browse a tree expression without knowledge about recursivity

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a simple equation parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582398/writing-a-simple-equation-parser)

Comment: @st0le I have never used Java Math Expression Parser. Can it handle operator associativity and precedence? If not, then does the OP require operator associativity and precedence?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equation (expression) parser with precedence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256/equation-expression-parser-with-precedence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowledge of compilation techniques it would be ugly.  But there is no need to learn a ton of compilation for an introductory example like this.

Look at something like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/345888/How-to-write-a-simple-interpreter-in-JavaScript and see if it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

See my [SO answer on how to write top down recursive descent parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163).  This method is very easy for expressions.