# Simple calculator in c with brackets

Tags: c, calculator, brackets

I tried to make simple calculator in c supporting +, -, * and / operators with brackets. For example `((2.1 - 5.6)*4)+(2.8+2 / 2.2)` should be -10.29... I tried like this but it works only with out barckets. I have no idea  how to deal if the user's input includes brackets.

```
float calc(void)
{
    float x,y, parse;
    char c;

    int test = scanf("%f %c %f", &x,&c,&y);
    if (test == 0){ // if '(' starts equation
        parse = calc();
        }

    else{
        if (c == '-'){
            return x - y;
        }
        else if (c == '/'){
            return x / y;
        }
        else if (c == '+'){
            return x + y;
        }
        else if (c == '*'){
            return x * y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to break this into two problems: 1) find all the brackets, pair them up, find their innermost contents; 2) evaluate these contents. It becomes a recursive code - the scope of explaining this in detail is outside of the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Comment: Or even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582398/writing-a-simple-equation-parser

Comment: you're not doing the math in correct precedence. Convert it to [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) by Shunting-yard algorithm and calculate

Answer (score 3):

Here you have the algorithm:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

What you are using is called infix notation by the way. What the algorithm seems to do is to transform this into postfix notation (which is much more easy to compute since you just need a stack).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot solve an equation that complicated with brackets in this simple way. There are some algorithms that you have to follow. One of them which is used in some calculators is **Reversed Polish Notation** where you transform the equation into a specific form, then using a stack you start pushing and popping to do the calculation taking into consideration priorities.

[Link to Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)

Comment: @amir-Nice and practical explanation here.An upvote from myside.